# SwiftUI change inner state button with action callback request

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have custom stack of two buttons here No/Yes. Both have external actions implemented. But, I can't find the way to do modify with **accept / decline** action, I need also to change inner

**@State var type: SelectionType = .none** - to **.yes** or **.no**

```swift
struct SegmentedButtonView: View {
    @State var type: SelectionType = .none
    var accept: () -> ()
    var decline: () -> ()
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            Button(action: accept ){
                Spacer()
                Text(SelectionType.no.rawValue)
                    .font(.Montserrat(weight: (type == .yes || type == .none) ? .SemiBold : .Bold, size: 16))
                    .foregroundColor((type == .none || type == .yes) ? Color.lightGray : Color.white)
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(height: 40)
            .background(type == .no ? Color.brand_purple : Color.white)

            Rectangle().vertical_line().background(type == .none ? Color.lightGray : Color.brand_purple)

            Button(action: decline){
                Spacer()
                Text(SelectionType.yes.rawValue)
                    .font(.Montserrat(weight: (type == .no || type == .none) ? .SemiBold : .Bold, size: 16))
                    .foregroundColor((type == .none || type == .no) ? Color.lightGray : Color.white)
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(height: 40)
            .background(type == .yes ? Color.brand_purple : Color.white)

        }.frame(width: 138, height: 40)
            .font(.Montserrat(weight: .Bold, size: 16))
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(7)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7)
                    .stroke(type != .none ? Color.brand_purple : Color.lightGray, lineWidth: 1))
    }
}
```

Comment: An idea: you can have the functions for handling accept/decline and change the SelectionType there.

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov Can you show me demo how to do that? For now its working by modifying type from external call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your needs, it can be like following

```
    HStack(alignment: .center) {
        Button(action: {
           self.accept()
           self.type = .yes
        } ){
```